# qgis2web clustered point features issues

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I try to make a cluster points layer map with a huge amount of points (i.e 300000) using qgis2web plugin. In QGIS I set my project layers with scale dependency accordingly to avoid performance redenring issues. Unfortunatley it's tooke 45 minutes after updating the previewto display the preview without displaying cluster points features.

Is there any workaround, or qgis2web plugin is limited to a maximum points features?

Answer (score 1):

Without something like a WFS server to handle that volume of data, this is going to struggle. qgis2web converts data into GeoJSON, and that volume of points is simply going to be hard work for your browser. Sorry not to have a better answer for you.

Comment: Thank Tom for your answer... Don’t know how to handle a WFS, but I’m gonna look for some tutorials on the net and I’ll give it a try... Regards